# “Object doesn't support this property or method” error - JQuery .validate method

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I encountered some problem, I don't know how to solved it. I got “Object doesn't support this property or method” error in using jquery-1.10.4 . The .validate method is not working for me. Please help.

This is my code

**login.html**

```
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="design.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="loginBouncy.js"></script>
<script src="modal.js"></script>
<script src="validate.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.validate.min"></script>

</head>
<div id='mask' class='close_modal'></div>

<div id="signup" class='modal_window'>



<img id="pane1" src="pane1.png"/>
<p id="label">SignUp</p>
<p id="label1">Personal&nbsp;Information</p>
<p id="label2">Account</p>
<p id="label3">Verification</p>
<hr id="hr1"/>
<form id="mainform" name="mainform" method="post" action="SignUp2.php">
<input type="text" name="data[]" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="First Name"/>
<input type="text" name="data[]" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name"/>
<input type="text" name="data[]" id="mname" name="mname" placeholder="M.I."/>
<input type="text" name="data[]" id="sadd"  name="sadd" placeholder="Street"/>
<input type="text" name="data[]" id="tadd"  name="tadd" placeholder="Town/City"/>
<input type="text" name="data[]" id="padd"  name="padd" placeholder="Province/State"/>
<input type="text" name="data[]" id="user2" name="user2" placeholder="Your Username"/>
<input type="password" name="data[]" id="pass2" name="pass2" placeholder="Your Password">
<input id="captcha" name="captcha" type="text" name="captcha" placeholder="Insert Captcha">
<img id="imgcaptcha" src="captcha.php" /><br>
<input type="text" name="data[]" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email"/>
<input type="button" id="btnSignUp"  placeholder="" onclick="error2()"/>
</input>
</form>

</div>
</html>
```

**validate.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#signup form').validate({
rules:{
    name:{
        required:true
    },
    email:{
        required:true,
        email:true
    },
    fname:{
        required:true
    },
    lname:{
        required:true
    },
    fname:{
        required:true
    },
    mname:{
        required:true
    },
    sadd:{
        required:true
    },
    tadd:{
        required:true
    },
    padd:{
        required:true
    },
    pass2:{
        required:true,
        minlength:4
    },
    user2:{
        required:true
    },
    captcha:
    {
        required:true
    },
    success:function(label){
        label.text('OK!').addClass('valid');
    }
    }
});
});
```

Comment: `<script src="jquery.validate.min"></script>`? - `<script src="jquery.validate.min.js"></script>` may be

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you are missing a `.js` in the script src

```
<script src="jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. :) But another error rise. "$.browser.msie is null or not an object." Im using an IE. Is there ay solution too?

Comment: @akoDwin `$.browser` is removed in jQuery version `1.9`. Currently you're using version `1.11`, One solution is to use [jQuery migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/) which is used to detect and restore APIs or features that have been deprecated in jQuery and removed as of version 1.9.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `.js` in the name of your jQuery validate plugin name, it should be:

```
<script src="jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<!------------------------------^^^ add .js here -->
```